# macOS 10.14: Cannot find stdio.h

Tags: macos, gcc, macos-mojave

I am trying to run the following hello world program:

```
  #include <stdio.h>                                                                                       

  int main(){                                                                                              
      printf("Hello, world!\n");                                                                           

      return 0;                                                                                            
  }
```

With my system's default C compiler located in `/usr/bin/gcc`, that works as expected. But when I am using the compiler I installed, GCC version 6.4, located in `$HOME/usr/bin/`, I get the following error:

```
$ gcc main.cc
main.c:1:19: fatal error: stdio.h: No such file or directory
#include <stdio.h>
```

Any idea on how to fix it? I've tried `xcode-select --install/reset`. Also, at first, compilation was failing with the system's gcc but I fixed it by creating the `/usr/include` directory. However, I need to use the compiler I've installed.

Comment: Maybe try disclosing which compiler you have installed and have to use? And what command you tried to compile?

Comment: What do you get if you run `which gcc` in Terminal?

Comment: @MarkSetchell The one I've installed myself. When running the system's, I used `/usr/bin/gcc main.cc`

Comment: Please be more specific about **how** you fixed `/usr/include`, and also about how you installed `gcc 6.4` because there doesn't appear to be a 6.4 release! https://www.gnu.org/software/gcc/releases.html

Comment: @MarkSetchell There is in your link (July 4, 2017). The releases are not in version-number order.

Comment: @KenThomases Thank you! I guess I’m older and more cross-eyed than I thought :-(